# How to only send a mail to someone?

Tags: java, email

I am working in an web app, where i have to send an email to my users after some event happens. I wont receive any mails from them. How to proceed with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

1. an [SMTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_servers#SMTP)
2. [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) (read [the guide](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html)). It sits ontop of [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to check whether my server supports RFC2554 or not. This will be check during authentication. My server definitely needs authentication. Do you have any answers?